# função jquery nao funciona com routeprovider angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Estou fazendo um aplicação web com **AngularJS** e fiz esse `routeprovider` para `single page`

```
angular.module("app").config(function($routeProvider){
$routeProvider.when("/Proposta", {
templateUrl:"Proposta.html",
controller :"ClienteController"
});
```

Pórem, eu tenho uma `function jquery` para interagir com um `input` de um formulário nessa página `proposta.html`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $("#valor1").maskMoney({
    symbol: 'R$ ',
    showSymbol: true,
    thousands: '.',
    decimal: ',',
    symbolStay: true
  });
})
```

Quando eu estou na página `index` e mudo para a página `proposta.html`, essa função não funciona.

Answer (score 2):

Você está executando a função `maskMoney` no momento que a página finaliza a carga (via `$()`). O jQuery então mapeia o *DOM object* que possui o ID #valor1, e aplica a função.

Em um segundo momento, o Angular interpreta o mapeamento de rota `/Proposta`, e adiciona os elementos de Proposta.html ao DOM. O problema é que a chamada jQuery já foi executada.

Solução: Execute o método .maskMoney dentro do *controller* `ClienteController`, guarantindo assim que os DOM elements de proposta.html já estejam carregados.

Comment: Obrigado OnoSendai... Funcionou!

Answer (score 1):

Complementando a resposta acima, se você criar uma diretiva, e injetar no seu campo input, a diretiva vai ser executada Após a criação do campo, com isso o código JQuery vai funcionar, creio que essa seja a solução mais simples e rápida para o problema.

Answer (score 1):

Dentro do arquivo ClienteController você pode criar uma função para iniciar todas as outras relacionadas a essa view. Por exemplo:

```
$scope.initFunctions = function(){
     $("#valor1").maskMoney({
        symbol: 'R$ ',
        showSymbol: true,
        thousands: '.',
        decimal: ',',
        symbolStay: true
     });
}
```

ou

```
$scope.initFunctions = function(){
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#valor1").maskMoney({
        symbol: 'R$ ',
        showSymbol: true,
        thousands: '.',
        decimal: ',',
        symbolStay: true
     });
   });
}
```

no arquivo Proposta.html inicie essa função chamando ela com ng-init="initFunctions()" que todas as funções serão carregadas.

Por algum motivo o RouterProvider juntamente com outros módulos não tem o funcionamento esperado, uma solução que eu encontrei foi utilizar o angular-ui-router que trabalha com stateProvider.